# Simulating a back button in PHP without javascript

Tags: php, user-interface, navigation, server-side

I need a "back" button but without the use of Javascript. I already thought of one possible approach:

Using a session variable (e.g. `$_SESSION['http_referer']`) which would be updated every time on every page whenever it's loaded,

- saving it's content to a variable (e.g. `$lastPage`) (for further use
  in the current page)
- assigning to it the value of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

But I'm not sure how efficient (or inefficient) this is. Is it at least correct?

Comment: One issue I ran into with the idea above is (at least with chrome) it pulls the page from a cache when you use the browser's back button.  This means that the session data is refreshed, and then screws everything up.

Comment: How does that "simulate a back button?" What is your definition of "simulate a back button?" Why without JavaScript? **Why do you need to fake it at all?**

Comment: Are your users on some weird customized browser that doesn't have a real back button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user can only go back on your site it's much better to keep track of which pages they've visited in a stack you store in the session instead of `_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER]`.  When the user clicks the "back" button, you can redirect to the page at the top of the stack (a page is added to the stack after it finishes loading, so the "back" button should use the previous page).   Note that this is not the same as a real back button at all.  Instead it is added to the real history as a new page.

Also note that writing to `_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` during script execution does nothing.

Comment: Well, what I was considering doing something like $_SERVER['back'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] every time a page was loaded, not the other way around (in fact, I don't think modifying a SERVER variable is even possible). But I hadn't considered the "real history" issue.