# back button for mobile websites

Tags: html, mobile, web

I have mobile website just HTML and css. I want to have a back button where user can go back to previous page.

history.go(-1) this method wont work on my mobile. how to code this back button. please help me

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should have javascript enabled on your phone's browser, then this should actually work:

```
<a href="history.go(-1)">Back to Results</a>
```

Important, it's not in "onclick" but in "href"

Comment: friend its not about my phone. i want something work without js. Is there any way to do this. thanks for quick reply

Comment: This is hardly accomplished without using javascript, you may try the solution posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762732/simulating-a-back-button-in-php-without-javascript  , but only html, this wont work! and there are no alternatives